# Divisor coming as null

Tags: sql, math, oracle11g

I Have to find the percentage difference between two numbers.

i am using the formula A-B/(A+B/2)

I.e

```
select round( ( A-B)/(A+B/2)) from dual;
```

where a and b are two numbers. Now if a and b is 0 then the divisor comes as zero. In this case what can be done to avoid error ? what is the percentage difference between two equal numbers or 0 ?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - Yes, of course:  `nvl(x/nullif(y,0),0)`

Comment: I guess that should be `(A+B)/2, not `A+B/2` which means `A+(B/2)`. Apart from that, I doubt you can expect any reasonable definition of this operation, unless your number representation supports infinity as a value.

Comment: The percentage difference of two equal numbers is 0. If you have no other Problems if A=0=B then just set it to zero (using if), as it obviously has no difference.